# I have two versions of Ubuntu in WSL

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04, wsl2

I'm trying to install WSL2 for work, and I think it has gone well. However I seem to have two Ubuntu versions. I only need Ubuntu 20.04. Does it matter if the Ubuntu 18.04 is listed? I can also see that 18-04 has a "*" next to it. Does this matter? If needed, how can I remove the 18.04 version?

```
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-18.04    Stopped         1
  Ubuntu-20.04    Running         2
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't matter if 18.04 is listed.  I have two versions too.

Comment: You can remove the same way you installed it. The asterisk means it’s the default distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can freely uninstall `Ubuntu-18.04`. The asterisk just means that it's your default distribution and will be used whenever you will not specify the distribution. If you want to uninstall `Ubuntu-18.04`, just remove the distribution from the store, or type `wsl --unregister Ubuntu-18.04`
But if you want you can keep it, and just set Ubuntu-20.04 as your default distro by using `wsl -s Ubuntu-20.04` for ease, as this is the distro you need.

Comment: Thank you! That's helpful. Just set 20.04 as default :)